# Embedding Links to WPForms on a WP Page

Tags: forms

I am not a developer but a new administrator on a website. I am trying to embed the provided WPForms link into the new WP Page I just added to this website. The link appears twice on the same page and neither links can be previewed. I've tried everything and thought I'd check here. Error messages are different for both links and are about:blank#blocked and "Sorry, the page you are looking for has an outdated link or is no longer available."
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Go to YOURWEBSITE.COM/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wpforms-overview

Step 2: Find the form you want to embed and copy the shortcode which appears on the page.

Step 3: Edit the page on which you want to embed the form.

Step 4: If you are using the Gutenberg editor, click on the "add block" icon (it looks like a circle with a plus sign inside). Then choose the "Shortcode" block. In the text field that the block provides, paste the shortcode you copied in step 2.

Step 4a: If you are using the Classic Editor instead of Gutenberg, simply paste the shortcode in the content area.

Step 5: Save/Update the page.